# How to get the value of inner div with class name?

Tags: jquery, html, class, dom

The html will look like

```
 <div class="class1 selected">
 <div class="innerclass">value</div>
 </div>
```

in "class1" the class "selected" will come via some condition. So I want to get the value of "innerclass" when "class1" has class "selected". How can I get this value via jquery?

Comment: $('.class1.selected .innerclass').text();

Comment: Thanks, @itzmukeshy7, got what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.class1.selected .innerclass').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below selector

```
 $('.class1.selected .innerclass').html(); //OR .text();
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/3y4x8cw1/5/

```
 if ( $('.class1').hasClass( "selected" ) ) {
   $('.innerclass').text();
 }
```

try this hope helps :)

Comment: Why we use `hasClass` and a `if` condition check when we can do it all just by a selector?

Comment: of course but we can do it in this way also looks understandable by everyone

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var value= $('div.class1.selected div.innerclass').html();
```

Comment: Why we use `hasClass` and a condition check when we can do it all just by a selector?